# for loop behaving weird

Tags: c++, c, gcc

This is my code:

```
for(b = 0; b < 3; b++)
{
    int col1 = 0;
    printf("b= %d\t" , b);
    fgets(payload, sizeof payload, f2);
    fputs(payload, stdout);
    char *token;

    token = strtok(payload, " ");
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    while ( token != NULL)
    {
        int pp;
        sscanf(token, "%d", &pp);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%d\n" ,pp);
        grapharray[b][col1++] = pp;
    }
}
```

In this code, I am taking some values from the file line by line and copying them into a 2D array. I am skipping the first two values from the file. Everything is working fine except my loop -- it copies the value correctly into location `grapharray[b][col1]`, where `b==0`, but then skips `b==1` and directly moves to `b==2` and copies the next row of the file at `grapharray[2][col1]`. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks so much, I will be grateful.

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code so it looks sane.

Comment: oh.. sir please tell me how to do that

Comment: Capitalizing the beginning of your sentences wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @tariq: I did it for you

Comment: @tariq select the code in the editor and then hit the curly brackets button

Comment: What is in the data file you are parsing? Could you give an example of the input?

Comment: @don : sir it is a csv file data is like numbers seperated by space i am reading a line seperating it by spaces and converting that token from string to int and putting it my array file is like                23 45 533 43 32

Comment: This is one of those situations where you will probably need to post more that just a code fragment, and the input data too.  Note that since the data appears to be space delimited, you could use a single fscanf() call to extract the token far more simply and with less code. `fscanf( "%*s %*s %d, %*s %*s", &pp )` will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Also add the output of your program. By "skipping" b==1, do you mean that you are not seeing a line that says 'b=1' ?

Answer (score 3):

if your second

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

returns NULL, your while loop won't be entered and it will look as if b=2 was discarded
=> check with a debugger the value of token and maybe review your parser.

**EDIT**:

If your parsed data contain a tab (\t) instead of a space, this is likely to happen. Maybe you want to use " \t" in your tokenizer.

Comment: sir but my all line have same number of entries

Comment: once again, check with a debugger or a printf: it's cheap and might narrow your field of investigation. If my supposition is true, then you can analyze this particular line or maybe dump your data...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read lines, one at a time from a file, fgets() is not the best tool. If there are more characters in the line that you have room for in the target array, these characters will not be read.

See [Using fgets to read strings from file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531629/using-fgets-to-read-strings-from-file-in-c)